Confused between marcher, se promener and une promenade
Confused when to use nouns ‘promenade’ or ‘marche‘when to use verbs ‘se promener’ or ‘marcher’.
On google translate:
I went for a walk - je suis allé faire une promenade
I went for a walk this weekend - je suis allé faire le week-end
My general impression is that French people avoid using the noun but here it changes from noun to verb by adding le weekend.
Also when is marcher used as opposed to se promener?  I saw for example:
Ils aimaient marcher dans les collines’. Why not se promener?
Thanks for your help

Google translate: "I took a walk along the beach." — "J'ai fait une promenade le long de la plage." But "I strolled along the beach." — "Je me suis promené le long de la plage." I really wouldn't put much faith in Google translate for subtle shades of meaning like this. (Although there really is a difference between marcher and se promener — see the linked question.)
